# Can't find style conflicting with Bootstrap in Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

I'm having a very stange problem that I can not figure out.  I'm using Bootstrap to design a site, but I'm also including an custom stylesheet after Bootstrap to alter some of the styles.

The issue I am having is that in Firefox version 23.0.1 on a Mac, the text within the select list is off center vertically.  It's too high.  The styling on the options is also off, meaning, they don't have the proper padding that bootstrap normally applies.

Here's the HTML for the select:

```
<select name="sort" id="sort" style="display:inline-block;width:400px;margin-top:20px;margin-left:20px;"class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option %%GLOBAL_SortFeaturedSelected%% value="featured">%%LNG_FeaturedItems%%</option>
    <option %%GLOBAL_SortNewestSelected%% value="newest">%%LNG_NewestItems%%</option>
    <option %%GLOBAL_SortBestSellingSelected%% value="bestselling">%%LNG_Bestselling%%</option>
    <option %%GLOBAL_SortAlphaAsc%% value="alphaasc">%%LNG_AlphaAsc%%</option>
    <option %%GLOBAL_SortAlphaDesc%% value="alphadesc">%%LNG_AlphaDesc%%</option>
    <option %%GLOBAL_SortAvgReview%% value="avgcustomerreview">%%LNG_AvgCustomerReview%%</option>
    <option %%GLOBAL_SortPriceAsc%% value="priceasc">%%LNG_PriceAsc%%</option>
    <option %%GLOBAL_SortPriceDesc%% value="pricedesc">%%LNG_PriceDesc%%</option>
</select>
```

When I remove my custom stylsheet, the select list appears correctly.  Here is a jsfiddle with both Bootstrap and my stylesheet included:

http://jsfiddle.net/VrenT/1/

Here's the same exact jsfiddle, except with my stylesheet removed and only Bootstrap included:

http://jsfiddle.net/UwwvU/1/

As you can see, the styling for the select in the first jsfiddle is off, but I can not figure out what declaration in my custom sheet is causing this to occur.

I don't see the issue in Chrome, and I don't even see it in the same version of Firefox on a PC.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: Don't have FF on Mac here and everything looks identical in all Windows browsers for me, but I can recommend you install Firebug, inspect the element in question, then select "Computed" in the Firebug right hand panel, expand all computed styles and see what styles are being applied from your stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you @Strelok!  I thought I had checked every single style within the "Style" tab, but your comment inspired me to try the "Computed" tab, which I've never used before.  It turns out that the line height is being set slightly differently because my stylesheet is using a different font.  Since the line height is set as a multiple of the font-height, the new font is throwing off the calculation.  I am still confused how I can fix this though.  When I change the line height on the select, it doesn't seem to effect anything.

Comment: I tried on my FF on Mac 23.0.1, the two fiddles look the same. Then I saw that there is no CSS in either of them. Did I miss something? or did you not place the right CSS into the fiddles?

Comment: Thanks for checking @stevel. The css is included as an external resource to the jsfiddles.  It looks the same now because I've been updating it to get it fixed.  I just reverted it back to the original files so you can see the issue.  Let me know if you can see it now.

Comment: Nope, can't see it, the two fiddles are still the same. Guess I might not be able to help you here then. If you correctly show your fiddles maybe others can...